# Error while executing javascript promises

Tags: promise, es6-promise

I am getting console error as:**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.**

I wish to know where I am going wrong in my concepts..Thanks

```js
const myImage = document.querySelector("img");
const myRequest = new Request('elephant.jpg');
   // console.log(myRequest)
 fetch(myRequest)
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`)
    }
    else {
        console.log(`no HTTP error, elephant.jpg file is present,Status: ${response.status}`)
        myBlob=response.blob();
        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(response)
        
    }
   })
```

```html
    <h1>Fetch Request example</h1>
    <img src="" />
```

Comment: is the image path correct?

Comment: yea... (i have it in the same folder where my html ,js files are there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coding alone will not help you all the time, but also knowing when & how to **DEBUG** will!

You're very close in getting the desired outcome. Lets go step by step to see what you're missing..

If you log `response.blob()`, it will return `Promise {<pending>}`, means you aren't awaiting for this to complete, the executions proceeds to next line `window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);` where `myBlob` is still empty.

And this is when `async await` comes to the rescue.

```
fetch(myRequest).then(async (response) => {
    .. your code 
    myBlob = await response.blob()
}
```

And secondly,

```
the `src` property would need the BLOB to display the image so,
myImage.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
```

Good luck with promises!

---

My code:

```
const myImage = document.querySelector("img");
const myRequest = new Request("elephant.jpeg");
fetch(myRequest).then(async (response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
  } else {
    console.log(
      `no HTTP error, elephant.jpg file is present,Status: ${response.status}`
    );
    myBlob = await response.blob() // ensure this is defined in your file
    const objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    myImage.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);

  }
});
```

Comment: Can you share me your javascript code snippet so that I can compare where I am going wrong..thanks

Comment: updated, there you go!

Comment: works now ;  as per your comment but one query I did a console.log(myBlob) and it showed me Promise:pending and then

Answer (score -1):

Double check to make sure you have the right image url.
As it shows in your code, you need the image in the same folder as your code.

Comment: yea i double checked ..(Image is in the same folder where my html ,js files are there)